# Can I hide time and date and size in Nginx webserver directory listings?

Tags: nginx, directory

By default Nginx webserver shows the date , time and the size of all uploaded files when you browse each directory . It's something like " 21-Apr-2016 07:38           719858135 " . Is there a way to hide these informations and only list the links in webserver directory listings ?

Answer (score 0):

Adding autoindex_localtime on; in the location directive would format the Date/Time to you local format, but I can't see a way to hide them.

Comment: So this is completely impossible ?